# How do you set a custom status in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to set a custom status message for my discord.js bot but I can't find anything online the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence) don't seem to contain anything on it (probably because it's a relatively new feature) so I was wondering if there was a dev build or a way to get around it?

The current way of setting status is

```
client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: 'with discord.js' }, status: 'idle' })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Thanks for any help

Edit: [This PR](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/3353) is waiting to be accepted to add this feature. I'll post an answer when it's approved.

Comment: You can't yet: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3552

Comment: Should be closed